# Add labels for x and y using the plotmatrix function MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plotmatrix

I managed to plot a matrix (16X16) but I want to add labels for each single x and y axis's. As shown below, the labels are written vertically on the y and mixed with each other and also written on the x graph itself and also mixed. Is there a way to add the labels beside the axis without being mixed (as show in the second photo)?

Current graph:
[image]

What I want to do:
[image]

My code (just stopped after plotting three label as it wasn't working):

```
[~,ax] = plotmatrix(corr);
ylabel(ax(1,1),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP')
ylabel(ax(2,1),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP')
ylabel(ax(3,1),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP')
xlabel(ax(16,1),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP')
xlabel(ax(16,2),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP')
xlabel(ax(16,3),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP')
```

Comment: is the x-label and y-labels the same? so perhaps you  could do `[~,~,HbigAxe] = plotmatrix(corr); xlabel(HbigAxe,'ABCDEF'),ylabel(HbigAxe,'ABCDEF')`?

Comment: no they are different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your problem you want to be able to give individual y-labels for the rows and x-labels for the columns. Unfortunately when you use `xlabel` and `ylabel` the resulting text overlaps. Here are two solutions

### Solution 1: Use the big-axes to set the labels

Use single label for the horizontal axis and vertical axis by referencing the big-axes

```
[~,~,HBigAxe] = plotmatrix(corr);
xlabel(HBigAxe,'Horizontal Label for Columns');
ylabel(HBigAxe,'Vertical Label for Rows');
```

[image: Using Big Axis Label]

## Solution 2: use rotation and alignment to avoid overlapping labels

If you want each row and column to have there own labels you can rotate and set the horizontal alignment of the label. For example:

```
[~,ax] = plotmatrix(corr);
ylabel(ax(1,1),'Y Axis Label','Rotation',0,'HorizontalAlignment','right')
xlabel(ax(end,1),'X Axis Label','Rotation',90,'HorizontalAlignment','right')
```

[image: Individual labels]